# Convolution of a box function over the hypercube

Tags: definite-integrals, convolution

This looks like a simple convolution over the $p$-dimensional hypercube, but I am unable to find a closed form expression for arbitrary integer $p$:

$$f_p(a)=\int_0^1 dx_1\int_0^1 dx_2\cdots \int_0^1 dx_p\, B(x_1-x_2)B(x_2-x_3)\cdots B(x_{p-1}-x_{p})B(x_p-x_1),$$
where the box function $B(x)=1$ for $|x|<a$ and $B(x)=0$ for $|x|>a$, with $0<a<1$.
For small $p$
$$f_2(a)=2a-a^2,\;\;f_3(a)=3a^2-2a^3,$$
$$f_4(a)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}  \left(-7 a^4+8 a^3\right)&\text{if}\;\;0<a<1/2,\\
\frac{1}{3} \left(2 a^4-16 a^3+24 a^2-8 a+1\right)&\text{if}\;\;1/2<a<1.
\end{cases}$$

[image]
   
Related questions:

- What is the coefficient $c_p$ in the small-$a$ behavior
  $f_p(a)=c_pa^{p-1}+{\cal O}(a^p).$
- What is the large-$p$
  asymptotics?
- Can the calculation (even numerically) be
  simplified by Fourier transformation?

The hypercube integral arose from this [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/331993/11260) question.

---

**Update, September 2023:**

a closed-form expression for the coefficient $c_p$ was found by [Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/a/455095/11260), following up on fedja's comment here below:

$$c_p=\frac{2^{p-1} }{(p-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor}(-1)^{k}\binom pk\Big(\frac p2-k\Big)^{p-1}$$
$$=\{2,3,16/3,115/12,88/5\}\;\;\text{for}\;\; p=2,3,\ldots 6.$$
For large $p$ the coefficient $c_p\rightarrow 2^p(2\pi p/3)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Hmmm... I doubt that the top eigenfunction (or the eigenvalue) of the operator $Tf(x)=\int_{0<y<1, |x-y|<a}f(y)dy$ has an explicit formula, but, of course, I'll be happy to be proved wrong :-)

Comment: @CarloBeenaker $c_p$ is about (slightly less than) $2^p/\sqrt{2\pi(p-1)/3}$ for large $p$. It is just $2^{p-1}$ times the probability that the random walk starting at $0$ with $p-1$ iid steps uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ will end in the interval $[-1,1]$. Starting with $p=5$ or $6$ the normal approximation for the distribution of the ending position should be fairly precise, so you can compare your exact values with the corresponding integral of the Gaussian density.

Comment: Another interpretation of $c_p$ is the $(p-1)$ volume of the intersection of a hypercube with the hyperplane passing through $0$ normal to $(1,1,\dots,1)$.  I did some quick googling and found formulas for this quantity that seem to lead to the same result as that of Iosif Pinelis.  So just an interesting aside at this point.